# Nested AJAX calls to a site

Tags: ajax, services

I've been making this cordova app against this casting agency website, and I've come across this nasty situation where I need to list each user's created nodes. For this purpose, I have created a view with the contextual filter `uid` and it's taking the uid from the logged user. I also have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kartagis/7pvogueL/15/) where I am trying to list each user's nodes. However, it's returning empty (2<sup>nd</sup> ajax call). The weird thing is, it lists the nodes by the logged in user on [this URL](http://www.rejicast.com/user?destination=oyuncularim.json) username is `tolga` and password is `111222`.

The steps I have taken to debug:

- Hardcode the username and password.
- Hardcode the uid in the 2<sup>nd</sup> ajax call without deleting the 1<sup>st</sup> one.
- Delete the 1<sup>st</sup> ajax call.
- After deleting the 1<sup>st</sup> call, hardcode the uid in the 2<sup>nd</sup> call.
- After deleting the 1<sup>st</sup> call, not pass the uid at all because I have configured the contextual filter to take the uid from the logged in user.

Nothing worked. Am I missing something? Do I need to use something like [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)?

UPDATE: I tried using Services Views, and I ended up a whole lot of `404: Resource not found` messages. Docs for the module and views say different things for path; docs say `http://www.example.com/<endpoint-path>/views/<view-name>` while the view says to put the path name after the endpoint path (in my case, `services`)

Comment: Just to clarify.. Is the issue the ajax contextual filter value is not working with the view? In the fiddle it is showing your list of nodes [like your example data](http://www.rejicast.com/user?destination=oyuncularim.json) via console (which is a success in your 2nd ajax call)

Comment: @DMAC are you seeing `nodes` as empty? Because it's not empty. I see it empty as well.

Comment: You don't need to use views in between end point. Your path would be like http:// www.example.com/ <endpoint-path>/ <view-name> and need to enable  services for this views service.

Comment: @DMAC my bad, the URL was not showing `nodes` as empty, I had changed the view and it was because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the hard way that what was not working on jsfiddle.net was actually working on mobile. I wasted my own evening on this issue :S Thanks for all the comments though guys.